# Get applications to display behind the taskbar

Tags: menu, customization, taskbar

I just installed ubuntu and I'm trying customize it a bit and I have a question.
How do you get applications to display behind the taskbar?

I will elaborate.

[screenshot of desktop; i am not allowed to embed images in askubuntu yet :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPgHS.png)

like in this image, how do i get firefox to still display, not cut off in the taskbar area. Not to make the taskbar disappear, but just to display behind it? Please help.

P.S:
My version is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
(I am running a hyper-v virtual machine ubuntu).
I have GNOME Tweaks and dconf manager installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the taskbar to permanently cover the bottom of the Firefox window? This is not as such supported because it would become impossible to interact with the content below it. Instead you can set the taskbar to hide, and moving the mouse to the bottom edge will have it appear over the applications.

Comment: k, thanks a ton bro